# Data not being posted from HTML form

Tags: html, forms

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="/configure-game/" method="post" id="roles_form">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='HIKbFT3HVUuiKG0UkShoYabAmvVov7NE' />
    <input type="text" id="rolenum1" value="0">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum2" value="1">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum3" value="2">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum4" value="3">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum5" value="4">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum6" value="5">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum7" value="6">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum8" value="7">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum9" value="8">
    <input type="text" id="rolenum10" value="9">
</form>
```

I submit it (through javascript), and it submits, but the only input that actually gets POSTed is the CSRF middleware token. I've tried this in both chrome and firefox, but I can't see what makes this HTML form different than a working one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the name attributes on all of your form inputs:

```
<form action="/configure-game/" method="post" id="roles_form">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='HIKbFT3HVUuiKG0UkShoYabAmvVov7NE' />
    <input type="text" name="rolenum1" id="rolenum1" value="0">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum2" id="rolenum2" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum3" id="rolenum3" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum4" id="rolenum4" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum5" id="rolenum5" value="4">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum6" id="rolenum6" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum7" id="rolenum7" value="6">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum8" id="rolenum8" value="7">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum9" id="rolenum9" value="8">
    <input type="text" name="rolenum10" id="rolenum10" value="9">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, I misread things and thought that was done by `id` - thanks.